# Deserialize Json with Gson on Fire with custom TypeSelector

Tags: java, generics, gson

I have 3 different types of json. I want to deserialize them into objects according to a field inside the json itself.

I've choosen Gson on Fire for this task [github](https://github.com/julman99/gson-fire).
There is an example of TypeSelectors that pretty much matches my needs.

So I wrote:

```
public static Base buildFromJson(String json) {
    GsonFireBuilder builder = new GsonFireBuilder().registerTypeSelector(Base.class, new TypeSelector<Base>() {
        @Override
        public Class<? extends Base> getClassForElement(JsonElement jsonElement) {
            String type = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().get("typ").getAsString();
            if (Type.A.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(type)) { return A.class; }
            else if (Type.B.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(type)) { return B.class; }
            else if (Type.C.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(type)) { return C.class; }
            else { return null; }
        }
    });
Gson gson = builder.createGson();
//...
}
```

But here I am stuck. I need to know how to return an instance of `A`, `B` or `C`.
The `gson` takes `gson.fromJson(json, Base.class);` where the custom TypeSelector should apply.
But I am not able to figure out how to return the desired instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"**typ**" should be a property of your base class. so we should be able to get desired instance in this manner:

```
GsonFireBuilder builder = new GsonFireBuilder()
        .registerTypeSelector(Base.class, new TypeSelector<Base>() {
            @Override
            public Class<? extends Base> getClassForElement(JsonElement readElement) {
                String typ = readElement.getAsJsonObject().get("typ").getAsString();
                if("a".equals(typ)){
                    return A.class;
                } else if("b".equals(typ)) {
                    return B.class;
                } else { //"base".equals(typ)
                    return Base.class;
                }
            }
        });

    Gson gson = builder.createGson();

    A a = new A();
    a.typ = "a";

    B b = new B();
    b.typ = "b";

    Base base = new Base();
    base.typ = "base";

    String jsona = gson.toJson(a);
    String jsonb = gson.toJson(b);
    String jsonbase = gson.toJson(base);

    Base ba = gson.fromJson(jsona, Base.class); // ^ returns A
    Base bb = gson.fromJson(jsonb, Base.class); // ^ returns B
    Base bbase = gson.fromJson(jsonbase, Base.class); // ^ returns Base
```

You can find more examples on [github](https://github.com/julman99/gson-fire/tree/master/src/test/java/com/github/julman99/gsonfire/gson)

Comment: Thank you, you indeed put me in the right direction. I always got Base-objects regardless o what I was doing. What went wrong was, that I'ver used Enums for the different types A, B, C, but they were overridden by @SerializedName, so the matching always defaults to Base.class.